# Python RegEx that matches char followed/preceded by same char but uppercase/lowercase

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to build a regex which will find :
**aA, Aa, bB, cC**
but won't fit to : aB, aa, AA, aC, Ca.

-if we meed lowercase letter we want to check if next/previous letter is uppercase
-if we meed uppercase letter we want to check if next/previous letter is lowercase
-both uppercase/lowercase letters shouldnt get found by our regex

I want any char to be followed/preceded by the SAME CHAR but uppercase.

Comment: You may do it with  PyPi regex module using `(\p{L})(?!\1)(?i:\1)` ([demo](https://rextester.com/TSOD7785)), but not with Python `re`.

Comment: Do you have any idea how to do it using python re? And could you explain me what does your solution works, please?

Comment: With Python `re` module you will need to use a simpler `(?i)([^\W\d_])(\1)` and add some more code to check the matches.

Comment: The second string you give `Aa` which would be a match for you, does not follow the question, because it starts with an uppercase letter. `AA` would match then..

Comment: Edited. Sorry, my fault. I am trying to find two the same letters with different casing. Aa aA - correct, aa or AA - wrong.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - Out of curiosity, can this be done with purely any flavor of regex?

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers Not sure what you mean by "purely any flavor of regex". If you mean in "any flavor with just regex" then NO.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - "Purely regex" would have been a better description but with all flavors out there, I wanted that in somehow. Anyway, that was what I meant. Thank you.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers You might consider workarounds. See [for a sample way with Python `re`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53646827/3832970).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may do it with [PyPi regex module](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) (note it will work with Java, PCRE (PHP, R, Delphi), Perl, .NET, but won't work with ECMAScript (JavaScript, C++ `std::regex`), RE2 (Go, Google Apps Script)) using

```
(\p{L})(?!\1)(?i:\1)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VfVoLO/1) and a [proof it works in Python](https://rextester.com/TSOD7785):

```
import regex
rx = r'(\p{L})(?!\1)(?i:\1)'
print([x.group() for x in regex.finditer(rx, ' aA, Aa, bB, cC but not aB, aa, AA, aC, Ca')])
# => ['aA', 'Aa', 'bB', 'cC']
```

The solution is based on the inline modifier group `(?i:...)` inside which all chars are treated in a case insensitive way while other parts are case sensitive (granted there are no other `(?i)` or `re.I`).

**Details**

- `(\p{L})` - any letter captured into Group 1
- `(?!\1)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if the next char is absolutely identical to the one captured in Group 1 - note that the regex index is still right after the char captured with `(\p{L})`
- `(?i:\1)` - a case insensitive modifier group that contains a backreference to the value of Group 1 but since it matches it in a case insensitive way it could match both `a` and `A` - BUT the preceding lookahead excludes the variant with the alternate case (since the preceding `\1` matched in a case sensitive way).

**What about a `re` solution?**

In `re`, you cannot make part of a pattern optional as `(?i)` in any part of a pattern makes all of it case insensitive. Besides, `re` does not support modifier groups.

You may use something like

```
import re
rx = r'(?i)([^\W\d_])(\1)'
print([x.group() for x in re.finditer(rx, ' aA, Aa, bB, cC but not aB, aa, AA, aC, Ca') if x.group(1) != x.group(2)])
```

See the [Python demo](https://rextester.com/DAFD13752).

- `(?i)` - set the whole regex case insensitive
- `([^\W\d_])` - a letter is captured into Group 1
- `(\1)` - the same letter is captured into Group 2 (case insensitive, so `Aa`, `aA`, `aa` and `AA` will match).

The `if x.group(1) != x.group(2)` condition filters out the unwanted matches.

Comment: Thanks buddy. You're great.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with `re`:

```
import re
import string

pattern = re.compile('|'.join([''.join(i) for i in zip(list(string.ascii_lowercase), list(string.ascii_uppercase))])
pattern.search(your_text)
```

If you're looking for a repeated letter that switches case (either lower to upper or upper to lower), then you can use:

```
pattern = '|'.join([''.join(i) for i in zip(list(string.ascii_uppercase), list(string.ascii_lowercase))] + [''.join(i) for i in zip(list(string.ascii_lowercase), list(string.ascii_uppercase))])
```