# How can I use two patterns in re.search()?

Tags: python, regex

I have the following string `string = DdCcaaBbbB`. I want to delete all the combinations of the same letter that are of the following form, being `x` any letter: `xX`, `Xx`.

And I want to delete them one by one, in the example, first I would delete `Dd`, after `Cc`, `Bb` and finally `bB`.

What I have done so far is:

```
for letter in string.lower():
    try:
        string = string.replace(re.search(letter + letter.upper(), string).group(),'')
    except:
        try: 
            string = string.replace(re.search(letter.upper() + letter, string).group(),'')
        except:
            pass
```

But I am sure this is not the most pythonic way to do it. What has come up to my mind, and thus the question, is if I could combine the two patterns I am searching for. Any other suggestion or improvement is more than welcome!

Comment: Python version is 3.5

Comment: Looks like I have [already answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53646827/3832970) this question, see both regex and non-regex approaches explained.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do a case-insensitive regex search to find all combinations of the same two letters, then have a function check if they're of the `xX` or `Xx` format before deciding if it should be replaced (by nothing) or left alone.

```
def replacer(match):
    text = match.group()
    if (text[0].islower() and text[1].isupper()) or (text[0].isupper() and text[1].islower()):
        return ""
    return text

string = "DdCcaaBbbB"
pattern = r'([a-z])\1'
new_string = re.sub(pattern, replacer, string, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

There is a downside to this approach. Because the regex is matching case-insensitively, it won't let you test overlapping matches. So if you have an input string like `'BBbb'`, it will match the two capital `B`s and the two lowercase `b`s and not replace either pair, and it won't check the the `Bb` pair in the middle.

Unfortunately I don't think regex can solve that problem, since it has no way to transform cases in the middle of its search. We're already a bit beyond the bounds of the most basic regular expression specifications, since we need to use a backreference to even get as far as we did.